# Binary Tree and Geometric Distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, trees

I have the following algorithm for "constructing" a binary tree:

- A probability $p_g$ for elongation, i.e. adding an edge
- A probability $p_b$ for branching, i.e. adding to a node two "child" edges

Also it holds that $p_g$ + $p_b$ = 1.

- A resource value R, which serves as a way for my binary tree algorithm to halt: For each elongation, the resource value is reduced by one. At each branching point, a uniform random number $x$ from the unit interval is drawn, and then multiplied by the resource, whereas one side of the left child-edge receives x*resource and the right child-edge receives (1-x)*resource.

This procedure is continued until the resource is used up.

Now what I am inerested at is the distribution of the branchlengths in my binary tree, whereas a branchlength is defined as the length between two branching points. I assume that my branchlength accords to the Random Variables of a geometric distribution. Is it further correct to assume, that the resource parameter does nothing other then to define the support of the geometric distribution I am looking at?
I was wondering since I think that the resource can be understood as a halting probability, right? I.e. instead of resource, I could also introduce a halting probability $p_h$.  Would then subtrees with different values of resource correspond to subtrees with different halting probabilities, and hence their branchlengths to the random variables of geometric distribution with different parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Is $p_s + p_b = 1$?

Comment: You might want to state that, the way you present it makes it seem these are two independent values.

Comment: thanks, done...

Comment: When is the resource depleted? When $R \leq 0$?

Comment: yes, exactly. no resource = the algorithm halts, whereas no resource simply means that resource equals zero at the corresponding subtree.

Comment: But it seems like the resource can be negative, hence why I asked. For example, if $R$ starts at 1, and you branch with $x\in\left(0,1\right)$, both children will have a resource value that is less than one but greater than zero. Now elongating at either child will make the resource negative.

Comment: that is true, so lets say at each point/for each subtree where resource would become negative, the algorithm halts.

Comment: *nonpositive (I apologize for the pedantry, just want to make sure I understand this)

Comment: alright, nonpositive, yes. I think this detail does just not really matter for my question. I have implemented this algorithm and there I also handle the case where the resource could be negative specifically. Here, for the sake of simplicity, I have presented the algorithm only as far as I thought it would be relevant for my question. sorry for the imprecesion then from my side.

Comment: Is elongation supposed to add an edge to a leaf?